# The RESTful way to include or not include children of a resource?

Tags: api, rest, nested

Say I have a `team` object, that has a `name` property, a `city` property and a `players` property, where the `players` property is a an array of possibly many players. This is represented in an SQL database with a `teams` table and a `players` table, where each player has a `name` and a `team_id`.

Building a RESTful api based on this simple data-structure, I'm in doubt if there is a clear rule regarding, if the return object should/could include a list of players, when hitting `/teams/:id` ?

I have a view, that needs to show a team, and its players with their names, so:

1: Should `/teams/:id` join the two tables behind the scene and return the full `team` object, with a players property, that is an array of names and id's?

2: Should `/teams/:id` join the two tables behind the scene and return the `team` object, with a players property, that is an array of just id's that will then have to be queried one-by-one to `/players/:id` ?

3: Should two calls be made, one to `/teams/:id` and one to `/teams/:id/players` ?

4: Should a query string be used like this `/teams/:id?fields=name,city,players` ?

If either 2 or 3 is the way to go, how would one approach the situation, where a team could also have multiple cities, resulting in another `cities` table in the DB to keep it normalized? Should a new endpoint then be created at `/teams/:id/cities`.

When creating RESTful API's, is it the normalized datastructure in the DB that dictates the endpoints in the API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually with a RESTful API, it is best that the use-cases dictate the endpoints of the API, not necessarily the data structure.

If you sometimes need just the teams, sometimes need just the players of a team, and sometimes need both together, I would have 3 distinct calls, probably something like `/teams/:id`, `/players/:teamid` and `player-teams/:teamid` (or something similar).

The reason you want to do it this way is because it minimizes the number of HTTP requests that need to be made for any given page. Of all of the typical performance issues, an inflated number of HTTP requests is usually one of the most common performance hits, and usually one of the easiest to avoid.

That being said, you also don't want to go so crazy that you create an over-inflated API. Think through the typical use cases and make calls for those. Don't just implement every possible combination you can think of just for the sake of it. Remember [You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).

Comment: Thanks you very much for answering. The /player-teams/:teamid approach is interesting, never seen that before. What advantages does that approach have over the /teams/:id?fields=name,city,players ?

Comment: Clarity. I prefer to go with cleaner, query-string-less methods because I think they are clearer. If you just look at the route `player-teams/:team-id`, you know exactly what you can and can't pass, and have a reasonable guess as to what you'll get back. With a query string, you don't always know a) what fields you can pass and b) what the valid values for those fields are.

Comment: Won't you end with many endpoints like `players-cities`, `teams-cities`, `cities-team-players`?

Comment: Quite possibly if you need that many. If you have lots of ways you may need to slice and dice your info, another method may be to have a more generalized endpoint in which you can apply filters, such as `players?filter.city=louisville`

Comment: Also note the use of the word "need". As I said in the original answer, don't just implement any combination you can think of. Only implement the ones you are actually going to use.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest something like:

```
GET /teams
{
    "id" : 12,
    "name" : "MyTeam"
    "players" :
    {
        "self" : "http://my.server/players?teamName=MyTeam"
    },
    "city" :
    {
        "self" : "http://my.server/cities/MyCity"
    }
}

GET /cities
GET /cities/{cityId}
GET /players
GET /players/{playerId}
```

You can then use URIs to call out to get whatever other related resources you need. If you want the flexibility to embed values, you can use ?expand, such as:

```
GET /teams?expand=players
{
    "id" : 12,
    "name" : "MyTeam"
    "players" :
    {
        "self" : "http://my.server/players?teamName=MyTeam",
        [
            {
                 "name" : "Mary",
                 "number" : "12"
            },
            {
                 "name" : "Sally",
                 "number" : "15"
            }
         ]
    },
    "city" :
    {
        "self" : "http://my.server/cities/MyCity"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. Just to make sure I get your design philosophy, `/teams/:id/players` would potentially still be an endpoint for when just a list of players from one team is needed, and `/teams/:id?expand=players` would be an endpoint for when the team info AND the list of players is needed?

Comment: I would not implement both a query string and /teams/:id/players. You should pick the one that you prefer. If you do both, then you have to support multiple ways of doing the same thing forever. If I wanted all the players on a team, I would provide /players as an endpoint with the optional query parameter ?teamName=MyTeam. As for the second bit, yes, I would have /teams/:id?expand=players as an option.